# Metal iOS for beginners

Tags: ios, metal, cifilter, metalkit

I new to `iOS` development. I working on `CIFilters` and I want to make custom filter using metal framework in `iOS`.

But I couldn't find any beginner level resources that could help me to understand the process step by step.

Is there any book/video tutorials or something that teaches Metal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will find apple documentation, sample code, and videos. [link](https://developer.apple.com/metal/)

This website is will help you to understand metal: [link](https://metalbyexample.com/)

Metal in playground with Swift: [link](http://metalkit.org/2016/07/31/metal-performance-shaders-for-the-ipad-playground.html)